# What does the '.' after the 60 mean in the expression?

Tags: c++, c++11

What does the '.' after the 60 mean in the expression?

```
double timeSaved(int limit, int avgs, int dis)
{
    double time_limit = 60.*dis/limit;
    double time_avgs  = 60.*dis/avgs;
    double tsave = time_limit-time_avgs;
    tsave = 10*tsave+.5;
    tsave = ((int)tsave)/10.0;
    return tsave;
}
```

Comment: It is the same as `60.0`

Comment: `60` is an `int`, while `60.` is a `double` (same as `60.0`).

Comment: Aside: Rather than round to the nearest tenth with `tsave = 10*tsave+.5;   tsave = ((int)tsave)/10.0;`. use `tsave = round(tsave*10.0)/10.0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a floating point literal. Two possible syntax for a floating point literal are ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)):

```
digit-sequence(optional) . digit-sequence exponent(optional) suffix(optional)
```

or

```
digit-sequence . exponent(optional) suffix(optional)
```

Note that `exponent` and `suffix` are optional. Further in the first there is a `digit-sequence` after the `.` while in the second there isn't. `60.` is the same as `60.0`.

Without the `.` it is an [integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). Hence `60.` is of different type than `60`.